# Bootstrap - Make Responsive full-width template, non-responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using this template from Bootstrap 3: **[Bootstrap Dashboard Template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/)**

It's using the `.container-fluid` class, which is making the template fluid/responsive.

My question is - I want to benefit from the full-width template, but I don't want to support the responsive layout.

I wish to achieve this template layout: [image]

How can I do this, without having to deal with the responsive stuff?

Comment: I am looking for same exact solution. Can you share the solution you have applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**bootstrap documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) has a paragraph to disable responsiveness.

> Steps to disable page responsiveness
>
> 1. Omit the viewport `<meta>` mentioned in the [CSS docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile)
> 2. Override the `width` on the `.container` for each grid tier with a single width, for example `width: 970px !important;` Be sure that this
>      comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the
>      `!important` with media queries or some selector-fu.
> 3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
> 4. For grid layouts, use `.col-xs-*` classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device
>      grid scales to all resolutions.